# canonical macro definition for conditional with discrete choices from valid set

Tags: conditionals, xparse, ifthenelse

what is the canonical way to define a macro (presumably, now xparse is preferred) that acts differently based on one of a set of discrete choices.

```
\mymacro[a]{does one thing, e.g., print this in red}
\mymacro[b]{does another thing, e.g., print this in footnotesize}
\mymacro[c]{yet something else, e.g., shows a dagger}
\mymacro[uuu]{throw a latex error, because uuu is undefined}
```

I have written this a few times myself (with `ifthenelse`), but I don't know whether I butchered the intent.  is there a canonical way?

Comment: If optional argument could be integers instead of strings, then the canonical TeX approach would be to use `\ifcase`.

Comment: note xparse is only needed for old latex releases or legacy argument types  such as `g`. Most of the functionality is available with no package needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\str_case`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn\tmp_case:n#1{
\str_case:nnF{#1}{
 {}{nothing}
{a}{does~one~thing,~e.g.,~print~this~in~\textcolor{red}{red}}
{b}{does~another~thing,~e.g.,~print~this~in~{\footnotesize footnotesize}}
{c}{yet~something~else,~e.g.,~shows~a~dagger~$\dagger$}
}
{\PackageError{tmp}{bad~string:~#1}{}}
}


\NewDocumentCommand\mymacro{O{}}% why optional?
{\tmp_case:n{#1}}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\mymacro

\mymacro[a]

\mymacro[uuu]

\end{document}
```

which gives

```
! Package tmp Error: bad string: uuu.

See the tmp package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.25 \mymacro[uuu]
                  
?
```

[image]

Comment: better or worse than egreg's approach?

Comment: @ivoWelch egregs answer has two versions but the "modern* one is identical to this one more or less.

Comment: would it make sense to offer a package that encapsulates this somehow and becomes the recommended approach?

Comment: @ivoWelch what would a package have other than a comment `% use \str_case:nnF`  ?? it would have been no code at all and just simply  call to that if the syntax was `\mymacro{a}` the rest is just standard latex to define an optional argument I used `\NewDocumentCommand` but `\newcommand` would be the same. Either way they are the specific example so could not be part of a package.

Answer (score 2):

In my comment, I suggested the use of `\ifcase`, when the options are provided as integer alternatives.  If you insist on string options, however...

I'm not sure your question has a canonical answer, since the outcomes you specified in your MWE do not fit a pattern...for example "shows a dagger" does not make any use of the provided argument, whereas "print this in red" does.

So I formulated an approach that basically requires you to define all *actions* in terms of a single argument macro.  Where such actions typically would not need an argument, you have to create a macro that does so.

Basically, `\setoption[<option name>]{<action>}` is the syntax used to define *action*s (where, as mentioned, *action* is responsible for absorbing the principal argument provided to `\mymacro`).  Invocation is done with `\mymacro[<option name>]{<argument>}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\setoption#1#2{\expandafter\def\csname option#1\endcsname{#2}}
\newcommand\mymacro[1][undefined]{\ifcsname option#1\endcsname
    \def\next{\csname option#1\endcsname}%
  \else
    \def\next{\setundef{#1}}%
  \fi
  \next
}
\setoption{a}{\textcolor{red}}
\setoption{b}{\setfootsize}
\setoption{c}{\setdag}
\newcommand\setfootsize[1]{{\footnotesize#1}}
\newcommand\setdag[1]{$\dag$}% #1 discarded
\newcommand\setundef[2]{Undefined option: #1}% #2 discarded
\begin{document}
\mymacro[a]{does one thing, e.g., print this in red}

\mymacro[b]{does another thing, e.g., print this in footnotesize}

\mymacro[c]{yet something else, e.g., shows a dagger}

\mymacro[uuu]{throw a latex error, because uuu is undefined}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Surely *not* with `\ifthenelse`: with more than a few choices, nesting becomes impossible to follow:

```
\newcommand{\mymacro}[1][]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{nothing}{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{a}}{\textcolor{red}{Something}}{%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{b}}{{\footnotesize something}}{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{c}}{\textdagger}{%
          \ERROR
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}
```

(I don't even want to try and see if it's correct).

##### Possible alternative method

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\defineswitchmacro}[2]{%
  \@ifdefinable{#1}{%
    \newcommand#1[1][]{%
      \@ifundefined{\string#1@##1}{\ERROR}{\@nameuse{\string#1@##1}}%
    }%
    \defineswitchmacro@{#1}#2\relax\relax
  }%
}
\newcommand{\defineswitchmacro@}[3]{%
  \ifx#2\relax
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \@namedef{\string#1@#2}{#3}
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
    {\defineswitchmacro@{#1}}%
}
\makeatother

\defineswitchmacro{\mymacro}{
  {}{nothing}
  {a}{\textcolor{red}{Something}}
  {b}{{\footnotesize Something}}
  {c}{\textdagger}
}

\begin{document}

\mymacro\par
\mymacro[a]\par
\mymacro[b]\par
\mymacro[c]\par
\mymacro[uuu]

\end{document}
```

Use more meaningful error messages than what you'd get with `\ERROR`.

##### More modern method

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\defineswitchmacro}{mm}
 {% #1 = macro to define
  % #2 = cases
  \NewDocumentCommand{#1}{O{}}
   {
    \str_case:nnF { ##1 } { #2 } { \ERROR }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\defineswitchmacro{\mymacro}{
  {}{nothing}
  {a}{\textcolor{red}{Something}}
  {b}{{\footnotesize Something}}
  {c}{\textdagger}
}

\begin{document}

\mymacro\par
\mymacro[a]\par
\mymacro[b]\par
\mymacro[c]\par
\mymacro[uuu]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I love the more modern method approach.  alas, I am not marking this as solved only because there are multiple approaches and I am not sure which should be considered canonical.  Someone (david c?) can probably tell me whether this is preferred to his own answer.

Comment: @ivoWelch The difference is one command versus the ability of defining several with a uniform approach.